# Graphs are represented using oracle, where oracle is the adjacency matrix. Is there any simple example of this?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, oracles

I have been reading papers on graph theory in quantum computing. Mostly, papers explain that they use adjacency matrix to represent the graph. But I could't find the practical simple example to understand it better. **Does anybody know about such example?**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please provide a link to the paper?

Comment: Graph theory can be introduced in all sorts of contexts. What context are you looking at?

Comment: The wikipedia entry is full of examples for adjacency matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix Maybe something more specific on which part you are having trouble with...